# Why is the website (hosted in a Virtualbox) not available on the host system?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, virtualbox

I have installed the CentOS system in a VirtualBox.
Installed the Apache by

```
yum -y install httpd
```

I have change the owner to `Apache`.

```
chmod -R 774 /var/www
chown -R apache:apache /var/www
```

`CentOS` is available by `Putty` and `ping`  the host system.
I have creat an `index.html` and an `index.php` file but i can not call it by the browser (google Chrome) on the host system (windows 10).

Which config is additional to set, that I can call the webpage on the host system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. There is a firewall in centOS7.

After running the following commands, the webpage is available on the host system.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```